# Ускорить выполнение кода Python

Tags: python, алгоритм

Задача на разделение набора чисел на 2 части, так чтобы разность сумм элементов этих частей была минимальна. Необходимо вывести разность. Количество чисел в пределах 100, их значения до 1000000. Скрипт должен быть выполнен менее чем за секунду. При количестве чисел 20 - 25 код выполняется с огромной задержкой, больше 25 вообще не тянет. Хотелось бы разобраться. Заранее благодарен.

```
from random import randint
from itertools import combinations

myset = set(randint(1, 1000000) for k in range(randint(1, 20)))

half_numb = sum(myset) // 2

print(myset)

mylist = []
for i in range(1, len(myset)):
    for j in combinations(myset, i):
        a = sum(j)
        if a in range(half_numb - 1000000, half_numb + 1000000):
            mylist.append(abs(a - sum(myset - set(j))))
print(min(mylist))
```

Comment: Такие задачи нужно решать не тотальным перебором, а аналитически. Вы хотя бы представляете сколько существует комбинаций из 20 по 10, например?

Comment: Тут не сказано ничего про перестановки. Пройтись срезом [i:], [:i] и всего то.

Comment: Это же ряд, а не множество. В ряде важен порядок

Comment: "Задача на разделение числового ряда на 2 части" - как делается разбиение? На произвольные подмножества? На непрерывные подмассивы? Ещё как-то?

Comment: Как делится колбаса на 2 равные части? Одним резом.  Ряд это последовательность имеющая порядок. Это не мешок с шарами.)

Comment: Похоже на эту задачку https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-array-into-two-arrays-to-minimize-sum-difference/description/

Comment: В прошлой вашей теме я же давал ссылку на более эффективное решение при приемлемых ограничениях на общую сумму

Comment: Я тестировал ту задачу. Такая же ситуация. При вводе относительно небольших значений код выполняется без проблем. Если количество чисел превышает 20, программа замирает.

Comment: Вычитание сетов можно тоже убрать. От перестановки мест слагаемых сумма не меняется.

Comment: @Giorgio85 Дело в размере чисел. Сложность приведенного по ссылке псевдополиномиального алгоритма O(n*sum), он проходит n раз по массиву длиной в половину общей суммы, до 5 миллиардов циклов. На компилируемом языке (Delphi) это занимает 2 секунды - всё равно многовато.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Будем использовать целое число в качестве битового массива. Бит установлен, если сумму равную номеру бита можно составить из чисел списка. Битовый массив обновляется с помощью логических операций.

Пусть битовый массив `bits` хранит текущие возможные суммы, а `v` - новое значение. Тогда `bits | (bits << v)` представляет возможные суммы с учетом прибавления нового значения. В коде используется более сложное выражение с использованием маски, чтобы в результат не попадали биты с номерами больше `target`. Начальное значение для `bits` - единица, что означает нулевую сумму. Номер старшего бита в конце вычисляется с помощью метода `bit_length()`.

Код укладывается в полсекунды:

```
import pprint
import random


n = int(input())
a = tuple(random.randint(1, 1000000) for _ in range(n))
sum_a = sum(a)
print('random list')
pprint.pprint(a, compact=True)
print('random list sum', sum_a)

target = sum_a // 2
print('target', target)

mask = (1 << (target + 1)) - 1

bits = 1
for v in a:
    bits |= (bits & (mask >> v)) << v

best = bits.bit_length() - 1
print('best result', best)
print('diff', sum_a - 2 * best)
```

> ```
> $ time echo 100 | python best-half-sum.py
> random list
> (774463, 428203, 965459, 818122, 193575, 281900, 888202, 463588, 843773, 745292,
>  364132, 133468, 894830, 119204, 413031, 2747, 848141, 555223, 511840, 157509,
>  984794, 533463, 77229, 865676, 353186, 913647, 855883, 315587, 593910, 726941,
>  729062, 399663, 213904, 359355, 890092, 52267, 105879, 168716, 373423, 231081,
>  595450, 17507, 844313, 765630, 531597, 721180, 29680, 664959, 784327, 656553,
>  74145, 837963, 454037, 357505, 667483, 421984, 453216, 979355, 505268, 932855,
>  483589, 19503, 39389, 129525, 605585, 467242, 245845, 89485, 351318, 751965,
>  639115, 693835, 401083, 414712, 212093, 366859, 243789, 123832, 679784, 942795,
>  789211, 907654, 799522, 398138, 555322, 664031, 665411, 794290, 837955, 822544,
>  640505, 580149, 598882, 333417, 491232, 245162, 7552, 932056, 50860, 217223)
> random list sum 50673926
> target 25336963
> best result 25336963
> diff 0
>
> real  0m0.440s
> user  0m0.364s
> sys   0m0.072s
> ```

Comment: О, нашли всё-таки способ быстрого апдейта.

Answer (score 1):

Проверка in range не эквивалентна проверке больше меньше. Да и смысл её не понятен. Она не уменьшает сложность. Если используете - используйте больше-меньше

Перевод в set не соответствует условиям задачи. Не вижу в условиях ничего связанного с уникальным множеством.

sum(set(j)) считается три раза. Посчитайте один раз то что можно посчитать один раз. sum(set(mylist)) вообще фэйл.

Зачем считаете комбинации? В условиях задачи ряд, а не множество. Ряд делится срезом.

Comment: Под словом ряд подразумевал набор, количество. Просто назвал так.

Comment: А задачу кто ставил? Там что написано дословно? Если не ряд, а множество - хорошо, оставляем комбинации. Но остальные ошибки давайте править. На пару порядков время можно уже сократить убрав range, set, sum

Comment: Если дословно, то имеется некоторое количество камней n (1 ≤ n ≤ 100) известного веса w1, w2, w3, ..., где w[i] – это целые положительные числа от 1 до 1000000 включительно. Напишите скрипт, который распределит камни в две кучи так, чтобы разность весов этих двух куч была минимальной. Количество камней и веса должны генерироваться случайным образом. Сам скрипт должен возвращать число, равное минимальной разности весов двух куч. На выполнение скрипта дается не более одной секунды.

Comment: Может стоит сначала отсортировать, а потом  найти границу, которая делит максимально близко к равенству. После этого можно пробовать улучшать, перемещая мелкие камни

Comment: @avp не улучшит ситуацию. Ведь [10,3,5,-18,-20] делится на [10,-20], [3,5,-18]

Comment: @eri, камни с отрицательным весом? (пахнет нобелевкой...)

Comment: Откуда камни? В условиях числа....

Answer (score 1):

Проблема с вашим кодом заключается в том, что вы используете функцию combinations из модуля itertools, которая создает все возможные комбинации элементов множества. Это приводит к экспоненциальному росту количества комбинаций и делает код неэффективным при больших наборах чисел.

Для решения этой задачи на поиск минимальной разности весов двух куч среди случайно сгенерированных камней, использую динамическое программирование. Это снизит сложность алгоритма до `O(n * sum)` и позволит эффективно решить задачу даже при больших значениях n и w[i].

```
from random import randint

def find_min_difference(numbers):
    total_sum = sum(numbers)  # Вычисляем сумму всех чисел в переданном наборе
    half_sum = total_sum // 2  # Половина суммы всех чисел, которую мы хотим приблизить

    dp = [False] * (half_sum + 1)  # Создаем список для динамического программирования
    dp[0] = True

    for num in numbers:
        for j in range(half_sum, num - 1, -1):
            dp[j] |= dp[j - num]  # Заполняем список возможными суммами чисел

    min_diff = total_sum
    for j in range(half_sum, -1, -1):
        if dp[j]:
            min_diff = total_sum - 2 * j  # Находим минимальную разницу сумм между двумя частями
            break

    return min_diff

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myset = set(randint(1, 1000000) for k in range(randint(1, 20)))  # Генерируем случайный набор чисел

    print("Входной набор чисел:", myset)
    min_difference = find_min_difference(myset)
    print("Минимальная разница:", min_difference)
```

Comment: В комментариях к вопросу я давал оценку такого способа - в заданное время он, увы, не укладывается.

Comment: Он почти укладывается если массивы NumPy.